# Retrieving AD information inside a mvc3 c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

I recently started a project where I have to authenticate users against the Active Directory.

Using authentication mode="Windows". I managed to login and retrieve the user name.

```
@Context.User.Identity.Name
```

Now I was wondering how I could get the GUID from the user that is logged in.

I want to use the GUID from the active directory in my own database to make its members unique.

Comment: Just adding this bit for future folks that see this thread: Using the `objectGuid` as your key (as the OP is) is /really/ *good* practice if you're going to track records in a database. `ObjectGuid` is immutable within a forest. If you do a cross-domain move within a forest, the guid will stay the same, but the SID won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here ... like grabbing the GUID
   var userGuid = user.Guid;
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD: